# C-Linked-List: How do I save the 'Head' in a 'Temp' var so I don't have to traverse backwards each time

Tags: c, string, linked-list

If I traverse my linked list for any reason, print, sort, etc... I have to re traverse it backwards to reset the head. Is there a better way to do this?

```
struct list_node {
  struct list_node *next;
  struct list_node *prev;
  char word[30];
  int word_count;
}; 
typedef struct list_node list_node;

struct list {
  struct list_node * head;
  int size;
};
typedef struct list list;

void print_list(list * l) {

    while(l->head) {
        printf("Word: %s\n", l->head->word);
        if(l->head->next != NULL)
            l->head = l->head->next;
        else
            break;
    }

//now i reverse traverse the list so I can call printlist again if needed

    while(l->head) {
        if(l->head->prev != NULL)
            l->head = l->head->prev;
        else
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: `struct list_node *node = l->head;`. And don't change `l->head` (or any other part of the list) in a function only intended to print it.

Comment: Why are you modifying your head pointer just for the traversal. Take a new node pointer, initialise it with head pointer. Use that to traverse the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to modify the original head pointer for the purpose of traversing the list. Take a temporary node pointer (local variable), initialise it with head pointer and use that for traversal. This way you won't be modifying the original head pointer of the list

```
  void print_list(list * l) {

        list_node *tmp = l->head; 

        while(tmp) {
            printf("Word: %s\n", tmp->word);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
```